# AngularJS ng-click: how to call a function with a function as parameter?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to code a confirmation-box-function (opens a modal), called within a ng-click directive.

Inside this confirmation-modal i have two buttons: Cancel + Ok.
A click on Cancel dismisses the modal.
A click on Ok has to call the (callback)-function given through my ng-click-call (with parameters):

```
<button ng-click="confirmBox('beSureQuestion', functionToCallWhenOkClicked(parameter))">Delete</button>
```

Is there a way to give a function as parameter inside the ng-click?

I dont want to use if-statements inside my html-template.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can easily do it by javascript ryt? Did you tried it by using javascript function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can do it the way you are trying to do. The problem is that ngClick will execute two functions `functionToCallWhenOkClicked(parameter)` and `confirmBox` at the same time because you invoke them immediately with `()`.

What you can do however is to pass a function reference like this:

```
<button ng-click="confirmBox('beSureQuestion', functionToCallWhenOkClicked)">Delete</button>
```

and them call it from controller when needed:

```
$scope.confirmBox = function(msg, okCallback) {
    // some checks ...
    okCallback();
}
```

**UPD.** From the comment by @Marcel Ennix. To be able to pass additional parameters it's optimal to pass one more argument to `confirmBox` function:

```
ng-click="confirmBox('beSureQuestion', functionToCallWhenOkClicked, {para1:value1, para2, value2})"
```

Comment: Yes, thats the way. Thank you! Let me add this important feature: to call my callbackFunction with paramaters i added a third parameter "para", in JSON-format: ng-click="confirmBox('beSureQuestion', functionToCallWhenOkClicked, {para1:value1, para2, value2})". Maybe you edit your answer with that?

Comment: Yes, this is good addition. In general it's a good idea to use object to pass many parameters and data. It can even be `confirmBox({message: 'beSureQuestion', callback: functionToCallWhenOkClicked, params: {}})`.

Comment: Oh, there is a typo in the extra-parameter: para2,value2 has to be para2:value2 (no commata) - @dfsq please edit

Answer (score 1):

As JavaScript is a functional programming language there are actually no differences between variables and functions. A variable is just a simple function returning its value. So to use functions as parameters simply pass the function to the view by adding it to `$scope` in your angular controller:

```
$scope.myCallback = function(anyParameter) {
    //do some stuff
    return "some stuff" + anyParameter;
}

$scope.anyFunction = function(value,callback,parameter) {
    //do something with value
    ...
    //do the callback
    callback(parameter);
}
```

now you can pass this callback function on within your template:

```
<div ng-click="anyFunction(someValue, myCallback, someParameter)">
```